# How can I find Miners' Wallet addresses?

Tags: bitcoin-core, miner-configuration

Is there any way to find miners' wallet addresses in Bitcoin Blockchain?
I would like to find transactions that are related to the miners themselves.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first transaction in every block is the coinbase transaction which is created by the miner of that block and which typically pays them the mining reward and transaction fees.

There is a high probability that the receiving addresses of coinbase transactions are addresses controlled by miners.

Pools may complicate this.

Comment: Thank you. Got the point. I have difficulty in realizing the first transaction in the block since all have the same blocktime and blockheight. I am not sure how I can pick the first one.

Comment: How to pick the first one: 1. Bitcoin Core: [`getblock`](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.21.0/rpc/blockchain/getblock/) will return all the transactions in block, first transaction `tx[0]` is coinbase tx. 2. Block Explorer: Easy to search any block, look at the first transaction, check its details and confirm its coinbase tx: https://mempool.space/block/00000000000000000009697358f5bc6c7084924996040f328f2baf55881c0636

Comment: Also the coinbase transaction probably has 0 fees, and 0 inputs (or inputs with 0 BTC) depending on what tools you use to look at it.